# Dynamically display column names in shiny app flashes error when dataset is changed

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have a shiny app where I want to allow the user to select a dataset based on a set of uploaded files and then specify the columns to display from the selected dataset. If I leave some columns selected and then switch datasets, an error flashes and is output to the console stating that the selected columns are unknown before the app switches datasets and displays it correctly. In my full app however, the app crashes, though I wasn't able to figure out how to reproduce the crash. I thought it might be related to some preprocessing that is done to add additional columns which are the same across datasets and which remain selected, but the error is the same without that feature.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("select_var", label = "Select Variables"),
  selectInput("dataset", label = NULL, choices = c("mtcars", "rock")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)


server <- function(session, input, output) {
  # define the dataset
  data <- reactive({switch(input$dataset,"rock" = rock,"mtcars" = mtcars)})

  # add a common column name that is always selected
  dataprocessed <- reactive({data <- data()
                             data$num <- seq(1:nrow(data))
                             return(data)})

  # dynamically generate the variable names
  observe({
    vchoices <- names(dataprocessed())
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "select_var", choices = vchoices, selected = c("num"))
  })

  # select the variables based on checkbox
  data_sel <- reactive({
    req(input$select_var)
    df_sel <- dataprocessed() %>% select(input$select_var) 
      })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(data_sel())
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add a conditional requirement using `req()` to test for column existence before rendering:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("select_var", label = "Select Variables"),
  selectInput("dataset", label = NULL, choices = c("mtcars", "rock")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  # define the dataset
  data <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,"rock" = rock,"mtcars" = mtcars)
  })

  # add a common column name that is always selected
  dataprocessed <- reactive({
    data <- data()
    data$num <- seq(1:nrow(data))
    return(data)
  })

  # dynamically generate the variable names
  observe({
    vchoices <- names(dataprocessed())
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "select_var", choices = vchoices, selected = c("num"))
  })

  # select the variables based on checkbox
  data_sel <- reactive({
    req(input$select_var)
    req(names(dataprocessed()) %in% input$select_var)
    a <- names(dataprocessed())[names(dataprocessed()) %in% input$select_var]
    df_sel <- dataprocessed() %>% select(a) 
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(data_sel())
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This will still output an error to the console.  Because `input$selet_var` has the observer which updates it based on the data, it seems like there should be no problem. Is it a timing thing?