# Unknown column error while switching the reports using drop down in dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

This error appears for a second then disappears but I am able to see the report. I have a demo to present. Please help me. Thank you.

```
library(shiny) 
library(DT)    
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "FILE", 
    "Select the Report:",
    choices = c("tbl1","tbl2","tbl3")),
  
  checkboxGroupInput(
    "col_n",
    "Columns to display:",
    choices = c()
  ),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("table_data")  
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  df <-  reactive ({ 
    switch(input$FILE, 
           "tbl1" = iris, 
           "tbl2" = mtcars,
           "tbl3" = faithful
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$FILE,{
    
    req(df()) 
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session,
      "col_n",
      choices = colnames(df()),
      selected = colnames(df())
    )
  })
  
  output$table_data <-   DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$col_n) 
    DT::datatable(
      df() %>% select_at(input$col_n),
      rownames = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't see any errors - the app appears to work fine. Can you clarify when specifically you see an error? Or what actions you take that result in the error? And are you viewing your app in an RStudio viewer window or in a browser?

Comment: I am running my app in the Rstudio windows. When you switch from tbl1 to tbl2 or tbl3 it displays. In half second it disappears. You will be seeing the error  in the console as well. But i am able to see the reports .The error does not  stop displaying the output.

Comment: Ok, I don't see the error in the app but do see it in the console. Sounds like your problem is a close duplicate of this one: [Dynamically display column names in shiny app flashes error when dataset is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818088/dynamically-display-column-names-in-shiny-app-flashes-error-when-dataset-is-chan), so the answer there should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `isolate(df())` because the app tries to subset again without changing the column names values although they're already gone.

```
output$table_data <- DT::renderDataTable({
  isolate(df()) %>% select_at(input$col_n)},
  rownames = FALSE
)
```

app:

```
library(shiny) 
library(DT)    
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "FILE", 
    "Select the Report:",
    choices = c("tbl1","tbl2","tbl3")),
  
  checkboxGroupInput(
    "col_n",
    "Columns to display:",
    choices = c()
  ),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("table_data")  
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  df <-  reactive ({ 
    switch(input$FILE, 
           "tbl1" = iris, 
           "tbl2" = mtcars,
           "tbl3" = faithful
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$FILE,{
    
    req(df()) 
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session,
      "col_n",
      choices = colnames(df()),
      selected = colnames(df())
    )
  })
  
      output$table_data <- DT::renderDataTable({
        isolate(df()) %>% select_at(input$col_n)},
        rownames = FALSE
      )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This didnt work . I got the same error.  Adding this code worked. req(all(input$col_n %in% names(df()))) . Thank you